MsAccess SQL updating tables
I have an old tool that I'm trying to update to a new data source. Everything on the tool seems to be working other than when I try to update specific records based on a load number. Now, this column changed from a NUMBER format, to now a STRING format. That is the only difference.
I have a button on a form that when clicked it runs two separate macro's. One that runs an update query to the WCL_DATABASE and the other updates the same records in another table (TrafficDatabase). When the button is clicked, I am getting the updates within my WCL_DATABASE table, but not my TrafficDatabase records.
Here is the SQL for the Update WCL_DATABASE
    UPDATE WCL_DATABASE_QUERY
SET WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.CARRIER = UCASE([Forms] ! [Edit_Load] ! [CARRIER])
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.COMMENTS = Forms ! Edit_Load ! [COMMENTS]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.DISPATCH_NOTES = Forms ! Edit_Load ! [DISPATCH_NOTES]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.CUSTOMER_CANCEL_DATE = [Forms] ! [Edit_Load] ! [CUSTOMER_CANCEL_DATE]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST = [Forms] ! [Edit_Load] ! [TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.RR_DATE = [Forms] ! [Edit_Load] ! [RR_DATE]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.RA_DATE = [Forms] ! [Edit_Load] ! [RA_DATE]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE = [Forms] ! [Edit_Load] ! [PLANNED_SHIP_DATE]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.CONFIRMATION_NUMBER = [Forms] ! [Edit_Load] ! [CONFIRMATION_NUMBER]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.WR_ID = [Forms] ! [Edit_Load] ! [WR_ID]
    ,WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.LAST_UPDATE = Now()
WHERE (
        ((WCL_DATABASE_QUERY ! SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER) = Forms ! Edit_Load ! SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER_Title)
        AND ((WCL_DATABASE_QUERY.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER) <> "0")
        );

and here is my SQL for updating the TrafficDatabase
UPDATE TrafficDatabase_Query
SET TrafficDatabase_Query.CARRIER_ID = ucase([Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [CARRIER])
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.COMMENTS = Forms ! Edit_Delivery ! [COMMENTS]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.DISPATCH_NOTES = Forms ! Edit_Delivery ! [DISPATCH_NOTES]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.CUSTOMER_CANCEL_DATE = [Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [CUSTOMER_CANCEL_DATE]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST = [Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.RR_DATE = [Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [RR_DATE]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.RA_DATE = [Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [RA_DATE]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE = [Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [PLANNED_SHIP_DATE]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.CONFIRMATION_NUMBER = [Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [CONFIRMATION_NUMBER]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.WR_ID = [Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [WR_ID]
    ,TrafficDatabase_Query.LAST_UPDATE = NOW()
WHERE (
        (([TrafficDatabase_Query] ! SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER) = Forms ! Edit_Load ! SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER_Title)
        AND (([TRAFFICDATABASE_Query] ! [SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER]) <> "0")
        );

I am getting an error when I run this and it errors on the TrafficDatabase update portion.

At this point I'm just not sure what to do, I've double checked all the fields to make sure they are all strings instead of numeric.

Perhaps this is usefull(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-running-macro)

Suggest you leave the macro business out of the picture for now.  Revise and test your SQL in the query designer.  Remove the spaces from before and after the ! characters.  That seems to be what the error message is complaining about.  However your first example includes those extra spaces ... and you indicate that one works.  I dunno how that is possible.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The CARRIER_ID field I believe is numeric so it would like a numeric value while you pass it a string value ucase([Forms] ! [Edit_Delivery] ! [CARRIER])

Please add a simple data and full table model, you tried or compile a question.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
